# Compare two files using linux commands

Tags: linux

I want to compare two unordered but similar data files. Is it possible to do so in linux. Is yes the how?

For example the contents of my first file are:

```
a=5 b=10 c=78
a=8 b=11 c=75
a=8 b=11 c=54
```

And the contents of my second file are:

```
a=8 b=11 c=75
a=5 b=10 c=78
```

Now want to find lines which are there in File 1 but are not there in File 2 or vice versa. That is, I want to find the difference between two files. Is it possible to do so using linux commands like grep, etc. Here the difference between two files is:    a=8 b=11 c=54

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28158/is-there-a-tool-to-get-the-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another ... Maybe this could help.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I tried all the solutions but they are not showing the different line for my case.

Answer (score 3):

Use `diff`!

First, sort both files:

```
sort a > a.sorted
sort b > b.sorted
```

Then apply `diff` to them:

```
myaut@panther:/tmp/files> diff -u a.sorted b.sorted 
--- a.sorted    2015-02-28 20:01:46.066305657 +0300
+++ b.sorted    2015-02-28 20:01:49.299210198 +0300
@@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
a=5 b=10 c=78
a=8 b=11 c=75
-a=9 b=12 c=54
```

Each line in `diff` output may be preceded with `-` of `+` sign. In this example:

- `-` means that marked line missing from file `b`, but exists in `a`.
- `+` will be shown if line exists in `b` but is not present in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

First sort your file as mentioned by myaut and use sdiff, it will show both files in 2 pan in screen and lines with difference will be marked with characher | in the dividing space in between the 2 pans.

```
cat file1 | sort > file1_sorted
cat file2 | sort > file2_sorted

sdiff file1_sorted file2_sorted | more
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have vim installed, try:

vim -f filename1 filename2

This will show you difference between two files in GUI form (Visualize).